# Replace string in list using dictionary in Python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, replace

How can I replace string in list using dictionary?

I have

```
text = ["h#**o+","+&&&orld"]
```

```
replacement = {"#":"e","*":"l","+":"w","&":""}
```

I want:

```
correct = ["Hellow 
           World"]
```

I have try:

```
def correct(text,replacement):
    for word, replacement in replacement.items():
        text = text.replace(word, replacement)
```

But:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Btw, the best you can expect here is "Hellow World"

Comment: you are looking fro `.translate`

Comment: What juanpa.arrivillaga said: look up maketrans() and translate() string methods. And also title() .

Comment: not convinced about maketrans/translate: `"&"` needs to be replaced by `""` here - is that supported by maketrans? which says both sets have to be equal in length.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your issue, please thank the person who provided it by accepting the answer. This will add to their reputation points.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is mostly correct except your `correct` function seems to be wanting to correct only a single `str` (e.g. `"h#**o+"` => `"hellow"`), whereas your variable `text` is currently a  `list` or `str`s. So if you want to get `"hellow world"` you need to call `correct` multiple times to get a list of corrected words, which you can then join into a string.

Try this runnable example!

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

words = ["h#**o+","+&&&orld"]
replacement = {"#":"e","*":"l","+":"w","&":""}

def correct(text,replacement):
    for word, replacement in replacement.items():
        text = text.replace(word, replacement)
    return text

def correct_multiple(words, replacement):
    new_words = [correct(word, replacement) for word in words] # get a list of results
    combined_str = " ".join(new_words) # join the list into a string
    return combined_str

output = correct_multiple(words, replacement)
print(f"{output=}")
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get "Hellow World" from output = "hellow world"?

Comment: @NJMSJMDCT I assumed `Hellow World` was just a typo in the input `["h#**o+","+&&&orld"]` (the first word ends with `+`). If this is not the case, writing specailized code to detect spelling errors is going to take more work. You would have to either add a dictionary into your program or make a web request to some webpage which can correct the spelling. Maybe there is a python package for spell-check... really not sure

Comment: For individual words, look into str.capiltalize().  i.e. `"world".capitalize()`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this too:

```
text = ["h#**o+","+&&&orld"]
replacement = {"#":"e","*":"l","+":"w","&":""}

string1 = " ".join(text)  # join the words into one string
string2 = string1.translate(string1.maketrans(replacement))
string3 = string2.title()

print(string1 + '\n' + string2 + '\n' + string3)
# h#**o+ +&&&orld
# hellow world
# Hellow World
```

I've separated the proceedings into 3 successive steps to demonstrate the effect of each step.

Answer (score 0):

`text` is a LIST of strings, not a string. You can't call string methods on it.

`text[0].replace()` would be a thing...

Comment: that is literally the premise of the question, though.

Comment: Sure- was trying to give a hint towards the homework question without providing the full answer, but maybe could have done a better job :)